# Something wrong with imagedashedline?

Tags: php, gd

Is there an error with the following code?

```
imagedashedline($image, $posax, $posay, $posbx, $posay, $black);
```

What it shows is:

[image: what happens with imagedashedline]

I tried it like this:

```
imageline($image, $posax, $posay, $posbx, $posay, $black);
```

And what it shows is:

[image: imageline seemingly works, but imagedashedline doesn't!]

and it worked perfectly in the gd code. What really befuddles me is the dashed line which is going vertically downwards. It is not being blocked at all. If it is because the triangle area overlaps it, then the bottom line should at least partially show. So what must be the error? Is it that `imagepolygon` has a higher z-index than `imagedashedline`, but not higher than `imageline`? (a polygon partially covers this should-be dashed line.) But both `imagedashedline` statements (one to create the vertical line and the other to create the horizontal line) are executed after the `imagepolygon` function, so they should both not show, if z-index is the case.

**EDIT:** I worked out the reason, and found that horizontal `imagedashedline` lines have a height of 0, making them invisible to the eye. Any other tilted angle will work, as long as you increase the `imagesetthickness` function value. See if that helps.

Comment: To make sure about the z-index logic, did you try swapping the order of lines?

Comment: yes, I have tried that multiple times, still not being able to succeed.

Comment: Here's another silly suggestion. I had a similar problem with some SVG path and by playing with its Y pixel location and thickness I solved it. Can you try these, just in case…

Comment: So you mean that the dashed line might be stuck under the red line?

Comment: **Bad news:** It's definitely a bug (check the comments in the PHP manual for this function) **Good news:** You might still have a chance because this function seems to be deprecated and replaced by combinational use of `imagesetstyle()` and `imageline()` functions, which makes me think this bug might have been fixed.

Comment: @inhan oh well, it still doesn't seem to work. Thank you for your time, it's getting late where I am. Goodbye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I found the answer - the horizontal line has a height of 0px as the line is completely horizontal. Making the line have the slightest tilt to it makes it visible again.